# How to use xquery to find node and addChild to it?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xquery

Is it possible to use xpath/xquery to query for a specific xml node, and then import/add a child node to it?

Example (code taken from http://codepad.org/gJ1Y2LjM , that was presented in similar question, but not the same):

1.
I want to add an array

```
$book = array('isbn'=>123456789099, 'title' => 'Harry Potter 3', 'author' => 'J K. Rowling', 'edition' => '2007');
```

2.
To an existing XML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <isbn>123456789098</isbn>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <edition>2005</edition>
    </book>
    <book>
        <placeItHere></placeItHere>
        <isbn>1</isbn>
        <title>stuffs</title>
        <author>DA</author>
        <edition>2014</edition>
    </book>
</books>');
```

3.
To do that it is used the following fragment.

```
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML("    <book>
<isbn>{$book['isbn']}</isbn>
        <title>{$book['title']}</title>
        <author>{$book['author']}</author>
        <edition>{$book['edition']}</edition>
    </book>
");
```

4.
But instead of appending it to the root node, has almost every example i found on internet:

```
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);
```

5.
I want to append it (p.ex) to the node found in /books/book/placeItHere and not using getElementbyId or tagName, but a xpath/xquery. I tryed

```
$xp = new domxpath($doc);
$parent = $xp->query("books/book/placeItHere");
```

to reach the node, but never managed to use it as the parent.

**Question: How to use that location to appendChild $fragment? Is it possible?**

```
**YOUR BEAUTIFUL MAGIC**
```

In the end I will just save it.

```
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Thank you for any help you can give to me.

Comment: Good question. Can you show us what code you tried, and what the result was? Did it give an error message?

Comment: i tried a lot of different approaches, but I think I'm missing something basic, like how to convert the result of the xquery to something that can be used as a DOMDocument. Normally error is: 'code' Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object 'code' -> when i try to use the $parent directly in any way related to the $dom. Examples: $parent->item(0)->appendChild($fragment); #ERROR... 
I'm trying to get previous examples, but I think I cant get them all right now because I'm not on my machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems:

1. Your xpath expression should be `/books/book/placeItHere` (with the leading `/`).
2. [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) rather than a [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), so you'll need to grab your [`item()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) from it.

I rarely recommend using document fragments as playing fast and loose with raw XML regularly leads to problems. For example if your book title included an ampersand `appendXML()` would crap out with a parser error.

Instead I suggest [`createElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and [`createTextNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php), which will handle transforming things like `&` into `&amp;` automatically.

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <isbn>123456789098</isbn>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <edition>2005</edition>
    </book>
    <book>
        <placeItHere></placeItHere>
        <isbn>1</isbn>
        <title>stuffs</title>
        <author>DA</author>
        <edition>2014</edition>
    </book>
</books>
XML;

$book = [
    'isbn'    => 123456789099,
    'title'   => 'Harry Potter 3',
    'author'  => 'J K. Rowling',
    'edition' => '2007'
];

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$placeItHere = $xpath->query('/books/book/placeItHere')->item(0);
$newBook = $placeItHere->appendChild($dom->createElement('book'));
foreach ($book as $part => $value) {
    $element = $newBook->appendChild($dom->createElement($part));
    $element->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value));
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

---

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <isbn>123456789098</isbn>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <edition>2005</edition>
  </book>
  <book>
    <placeItHere>
      <book>
        <isbn>123456789099</isbn>
        <title>Harry Potter 3</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <edition>2007</edition>
      </book>
    </placeItHere>
    <isbn>1</isbn>
    <title>stuffs</title>
    <author>DA</author>
    <edition>2014</edition>
  </book>
</books>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...I tryed: 
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$placeItHere = $xp->query('/books/book/placeItHere')->item(0);
$newBook = $placeItHere->appendChild($fragment);
And it worked (AWESOME!). I think I tried this before, but without the first '/', so thank you once more.
I was only using fragment because the actual code I'm importing is bigger and deeper than the example. Can you please teach me what kind of problem may arise from using the fragment option instead of creating every element?

Comment: @Paull Crovella: As in the comment on my question I tried: $placeItHere = $xpath->query("books/book/placeItHere"); $placeItHere->item(0)->appendChild($fragment); -> not working..... I tried your answer: $placeItHere = $xpath->query('/books/book/placeItHere')->item(0);
$placeItHere->appendChild($fragment); -> working...... I guess it was the problem with the leading '/' as pointed out by you (I'm ashamed right now :)...). Let me check the new answer and thank you for the answer about document fragment.

Comment: I Tried the ampersand, and has expected it throwed 7 warnings. I will definitely have your suggestion into account. Marked your answer as correct.